# What is activating effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, metal

In the book "Organic Chemistry" by Morrison and Boyd,It is written that

> *Sodium borohydride* cannot reduce weaker electrophiles like esters though *Lithium aluminum  hydride* can reduce esters to alcohols due to **stronger activating effect** of Li+ ion than Na+

What is **activating effect**?

(Google search did not give appropriate results.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a carbonyl group. We know that, under acidic conditions, $\ce{H+}$ can protonate on carbonyl $\ce{O}$ and hence activate the carbonyl group to nucleophilic attack at $\ce{C}$, and we call such an effect an **activating effect**. The metal ions $\ce{Li^+}$ and $\ce{Na^+}$ serve the same purpose as $\ce{H+}$, though $\ce{Li^+}$ is a stronger activator due to its high charge density and hence stronger attraction to $\ce{O}$.